# From a folder with images to a PICT file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to use [Pix2Pix](https://github.com/yining1023/pix2pix_tensorflowjs_lite) to generate new images. For this, I have already prepared a folder full of images. My app is also already working. The only problem now is: How can I create a `.pict` file?

Regarding the instructions that I have found, I need to train a model and then somehow can export a `.pict` file. But I didn't find any tutorial that showed me where I should locate my folder of images and how I can let it start to export such a file in the end.

It would be super cool to just do it with a web app. But I think it probably should be something like:

```
$ python load folder /user/documents/imagefolder
$ python run pix2pix
$ export .pict
```

How can this be written correctly?

Comment: The README on that GitHub repo includes example commands to run.

For instance: https://github.com/yining1023/pix2pix_tensorflowjs_lite#2-train-the-model

Shows how to use the `--input_dir` command line parameter to specify the directory where the training images are.

And then step 4 and 5 cover exporting and creating a `.pict` file.  Let us know what of those you're trying and what isn't working.

Comment: @Lectre Thank you. I wonder where the path "photos/original" should be. It doesn't seem to me like a full path. And I should use terminal for this stuff, right? Some stuff just doesn't work, for example "$ python edge-detection.py". It needs to be installed first probably, but how?

Comment: Yes, the commands mentioned in the README are intended to be run in the terminal. Regarding the path, generally (for most command line interfaces like this one) when you don't see a full path its relative to the location that you're running the script from.

Comment: There are a lot of instructions, referencing a number of other repositories, so I understand your confusion. You will want to download this other repo by the same Github account: https://github.com/yining1023/pix2pix-tensorflow ... (either Zip or git clone). That repo includes the "tools" directory with the various .py scripts (eg. "tools/split.py", "tools/edge-detection.py").

Comment: With the file paths, you can probably use absolute paths if you're more comfortable with that; otherwise you can make a "my_photos" folder within the "pix2pix-tensorflow" directory after you download that other repo. I'm suggest different name to avoid colliding with the existing "photos" folder with the pikachu files. Hope that helps (caveat, I didn't run this, I'm just piecing together the instructions).